# Parsing multiple JSON objects from File

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON file which contains the following

```
[
{"ID": 1, "timestamp": 10, "startingFloor": 1, "eventType": "enter"}, 
{"ID": 1, "timestamp": 10, "eventType": "call", "noOfCalls": 1}, 
{"ID": 1, "timestamp": 10, "startingFloor": 1, "eventType": "board"}, 
{"ID": 1, "timestamp": 10, "eventType": "weight", "currentLoad": 53},
{"ID": 1, "timestamp": 36, "eventType": "call", "noOfCalls": 2},  
{"ID": 2, "timestamp": 50, "eventType": "call", "noOfCalls": 3}, 
{"ID": 2, "timestamp": 15, "eventType": "call", "noOfCalls": 1}, 
{"ID": 2, "timestamp": 38, "eventType": "weight", "currentLoad": 84},
{"ID": 2, "timestamp": 27, "eventType": "call", "noOfCalls": 2}, 
{"ID": 2, "timestamp": 36, "startingFloor": 2, "eventType": "enter"}, 
{"ID": 3, "timestamp": 50, "startingFloor": 3, "eventType": "enter"}, 
{"ID": 4, "timestamp": 38, "startingFloor": 4, "eventType": "board"}, 
{"ID": 4, "timestamp": 27, "startingFloor": 4, "eventType": "enter"},
{"ID": 5, "timestamp": 15, "startingFloor": 5, "eventType": "enter"}
]
```

I need to be able to pull each line of this file out to interact with it similarly to a dictionary (for a very simple example I need to find the highest noOfCalls value).

The issue is that the file is a series of JSON objects so the normal ways of reading JSON files which I have used before do not work, such as;

```
with open('input.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

I have tried other methods such as trying to pull each object out and appending it to a list such as:

```
data = []
for line in open('input.json','r'):
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

but no version of this works either.

I have also tried various other methods but I always end up with errors such as "extra data", "expected value", etc.

Any information on parsing multiple JSON objects from a single file would be greatly appreciated, apologies for not having more code examples as a lot of the attempts I had I tried a replaced.

Comment: The first code snippet combined with the data presented works fine.

Comment: That JSON data is a single list containing multiple dictionaries. Are you saying that your file contains multiple lists like that?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a complete moron. The extra data error being thrown was on account of some comments I didn't expect to be an issue. Kill me now.

Comment: Ah. [JSON doesn't support comments](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open('input.json') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems work for me

```
    import json
    with open('input.json') as fr:
    data = json.loads(fr.read())

    for line in data:
        if 'noOfCalls' in line :
            print line['noOfCalls']
```